# Assigning 2 arrays key value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have two arrays

```
ar1 = ["jhon", "doe", "alex"];
ar2 = ["21", "22", "35"];
```

I want to convert them into an object just like following

```
obj=[
{name:'jhon',age:'21'},
{name:'doe', age:'22'},
{name:'alex', age:'35'}
]
```

how do I that in javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. (The simplest way would be a `for` loop.) ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map function:

```
var arr1 = ["jhon", "doe", "alex"];;
var arr2 = ["21", "22", "35"];

const obj = arr1.map((item, index) => {
  return {
   name: item,
   age: arr2[index]
  }
})
```

On the map function, just to clean the code, you can use an implicit return:

```
const obj = arr1.map((item, index) => ({
  name: item,
  age: arr2[index]
 })
)
```

Comment: `ar1` is undefined ;)

Comment: It was just a typo, the array are the arr1 and arr2

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use `map` function as below.

```js
    var arr1 = ["jhon", "doe", "alex"];;
    var arr2 = ["21", "22", "35"];

    var combined = arr1.map(function(item, index) {
        return {name: item, age: arr2[index]};
    });
```

Comment: if the length of arr2 is large, you will miss those values

Comment: This solution is question-specific. You are right about length, it will pitfall if the lengths different.

Comment: It's right, both arrays are of the same length. The solution works

Answer (score 0):

```js
   ar1 = ["jhon", "doe", "alex"];
   ar2 = ["21", "22", "35"];
let obj = function objMaker(ar1,ar2){let arr = []; ar1.map((item,index) => {let obj ={};obj['name']=item; obj['age']=ar2[index];arr.push(obj);}); console.log(arr);return arr;}(ar1,ar2);
```